# How to accomplish a child page navigation?

Tags: navigation, child-pages

I'm not finding any info on this, so I'm probably wording it incorrectly in my search. So I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have 50 pieces of content that'll be going on my wordpress site. Each piece of content will be broken down into 5-6 pages (each). So I made a custom page template for this.

My goal is to have a navigation that shows the child pages, so users can click through them easily to reference different sections of the content. But I don't want to do this manually per page.

I've tried searching for child-page navigations and the best I've come up with is a plugin that just lists the child-pages. This wont work because even on the child pages I want the navigation to show.

Any direction would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm outlining a solution for you, it uses [`get_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) to determine if there are any, then conditionally sets up the post id `$p_id` for the `child_of` parameter, so that the list of child pages from a certain parent always can be shown, by making use of [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages).

**Code:**

```
function wpse125273_child_page_nav() {
    global $post;

    $args = array( 
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $children = get_children( $args );

    if ( empty( $children ) ) {
        $p_id = $post->post_parent;
    } else {
        $p_id = $post->ID;
    }

    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $p_id,
        'post_type'   => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    wp_list_pages( $args );
}
```

*Note:* exemplary and untested